# Assign the results of console.log to a variable

Tags: meteor, youtube-api, meteor-blaze

Hi I currently working with the Youtube Api and have every thing working accept sending the Authorization which requires I send an Access Token.

My code to get the access token currently looks like this:

```
//Client 
Meteor.call("getAccessToken", function(error, accessToken){
  console.log(accessToken);
})


//server
Meteor.methods({
  getAccessToken : function() {
    try {
      return Meteor.user().services.google.accessToken;
    } catch(e) {
      return null;
    }
  }
});
```

It works to get the access token and prints it to the console but how to I save that value (the console.log(accessToken);) to a variable to that I can send it in my http.get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it against a template instance where you made the call,

You could store it as a global variable

You could give it a context to save it against

You could save it into a session variable.

```
Session.set("accessToken", accessToken);
```

it's really up to you how you want to structure it.

Comment: Thank you I ended up using a global variable.